# How to use probability dependent decrements to update a starting value

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

I thought I had figured out how to code up a solution for the below in the R programming language, however, I'm not sure that I make the daily reduction correctly and that my results make sense, so I'd be grateful for some feedback on what I'm doing:

In my analysis, cancer patients find themselves in a health state that lasts 14 days and provides a utility score of 0.85 (1 is the best utility score, 0 is the worst).

For these patients, there is a probability of toxicities AE1, AE2 and AE3, which last for 5 days during these 14 and reduce the utility by a certain percentage for these 5 days.

The probabilities of these occurring are:

```
p_AE1     <- 0.040   # probability of adverse event 1
p_AE2     <- 0.310   # probability of adverse event 2
p_AE3     <- 0.310   # probability of adverse event 3
```

The disutility of these toxicities are:

```
AE1_DisUtil <-0.45 # The percentage disutility of adverse event 1.
AE2_DisUtil <-0.19 # The percentage disutility of adverse event 2.
AE3_DisUtil <-0.36 # The percentage disutility of adverse event 3.
```

According to the original study these percentage reductions come from:

> We also applied utility reductions for episodes of toxicity - *Cost‐effectiveness analysis of oxaliplatin compared with 5‐fluorouracil/leucovorin in adjuvant treatment of stage III colon cancer in the US." Cancer: Interdisciplinary International Journal of the American Cancer Society 109.6 (2007): 1082-1089.   https://acsjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cncr.22512*

Thus, I assume these utility reductions last for the duration of the episode of toxicity, which is 5 days. So, for 5 days of the 14, cancer patients have a reduction in their utility by the above percentages.

I do the below to find one days worth of percentage discount:

```
daily_discount_AE_1 <- AE1_DisUtil/5
[1] 0.09
daily_discount_AE_2 <- AE2_DisUtil/5
[1] 0.038
daily_discount_AE_3 <- AE3_DisUtil/5
[1] 0.072
```

Then I create 5 days worth of percentage discount:

```
AE1_discounted_daily_utility <- daily_discount_AE_1  * 5 
[1] 0.45
AE2_discounted_daily_utility <- daily_discount_AE_2  * 5 
[1] 0.19
AE3_discounted_daily_utility <- daily_discount_AE_3  * 5 
[1] 0.36
```

I create the utility for the 14 days pre any percentage discount:

```
u_F <- 0.85
```

Then I create the percentage of this utility that comes from 5 days of discounting:

```
u_AE1 <- AE1_discounted_daily_utility * u_F 
[1] 0.3825
u_AE2 <- AE2_discounted_daily_utility * u_F
[1] 0.1615
u_AE3 <- AE3_discounted_daily_utility * u_F 
[1] 0.306
```

Then I take this decrement from baseline utility - dependent on the probability of this decrement occuring.

```
u_F_SoC <- u_F - p_AE1 * u_AE1 - p_AE2 * u_AE2 - p_AE3 * u_AE3
```

And get the following result:

```
u_F_SoC 
[1] 0.689775
```

Answer (score 0):

If those 5 days are worse off by x percentage, could it be as simple as:

Break 14 days of utility into daily utility, create 5 days of utility, make those 5 days whatever percentage worse off, take the 14 days and minus the 5 days worse off from those 14 days based on the probability they occur?

Not quite sure how you would code that tbh...

Comment: I would love to accept this as the answer, but I could really do with some code or pseudocode at least to understand it fully...